# google maps API v3 not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

To start off I'm fairly new to Javascript and the Google Maps API so any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm building a map with polygons to mark boundary locations and the ability to search an address to see what polygon the address is in. The code works for both Firefox and Chrome, but for some reason when I try to search an address in IE, the map just reloads rather than placing the marker at the appropriate location.

I've included all the functions I use. The microajax Javascript function is used to read the xml file that contains the coordinates of all the polygon shapes. Since the polygons are being rendered in IE, I dont believe this is the cause of the problem so I didnt include it. I'm at a loss for what the problem could be. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="microajax.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 30px; padding: 0px }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:800px; height:600px" text="If map is not present, this browser does not support Google Maps"></div>           

<div id="message"></div>    

<form onsubmit="showAddress()" action="#">
  <input id="search" size="60" type="text" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
  <input type="button" onclick="clearmarkers();" value="Clear markers" />
</form>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()">

<noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
  However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
  To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
  try again.
</noscript>


<script type="text/javascript">

 var gmarkers = [];
var polys = [];
var labels = [];
var glob;
var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;  

function initialize() {           

  var ontario = new google.maps.LatLng(50.397, -85.644);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: ontario,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  microAjax("xmloutput2.xml", function(data) {
  // ========= processing the polylines ===========
  var xmlDoc = xmlParse(data)
  var lhins = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("lhin");
  // read each line        
  for (var a = 0; a < lhins.length; a++) {           
    var label  = lhins[a].getAttribute("name");
    var colour = lhins[a].getAttribute("colour");
    // read each point on that line
    var points = lhins[a].getElementsByTagName("point");
    var pts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      pts[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lng")));                  
    }
    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths:pts,
      strokeColor:"#000000",
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: colour,
      fillOpacity: 0
    });
    poly.setMap(map);
    polys.push(poly);
    labels.push(label);   
    }


 function showAddress() {
  var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
  geo.geocode( { 'address': search}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    // How many results were found
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Found " +results.length +" results";
      // Loop through the results, placing markers          
      for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {                                           
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[i].geometry.location 
        });
        gmarkers.push(marker);
        glob=checkpoint(marker);                      
        if (glob == 99) {
          var infowindowoptions = {
            content: 'This address is not within a LHIN boundary'
          }
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infowindowoptions);

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });                          
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "<br>"+(i+1)+": "+ results[i].formatted_address +" "+ results[i].geometry.location +              "Outside of Bounds";
        }
        else {
          var infowindowoptions = {
            content: 'This address is in LHIN '+labels[glob]
          }
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infowindowoptions); 

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });                          
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "<br>"+(i+1)+": "+ results[i].formatted_address +" "+ results[i].geometry.location + 
          " - LHIN "+(glob+1)+"  "+labels[glob];
        }              
      }
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17)                 
    }  
    else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

function clearmarkers() {
  if (gmarkers) {
    for (i in gmarkers) {
      gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  gmarkers.length = 0;
  }
}


function checkpoint(marker) {
  var LNum;
  var point = marker.getPosition();
  for (var i=0; i<polys.length; i++) {        
    if (polys[i].containsLatLng(point)) {
          Lnum = i;
          i = 999; // Jump out of loop
          }
        else {
          Lnum = 99
        }
    }
    return Lnum
};

// Polygon getBounds extension - google-maps-extensions
// http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-extensions/source/browse/google.maps.Polygon.getBounds.js
if (!google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds) {
  google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds = function(latLng) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var paths = this.getPaths();
  var path;

  for (var p = 0; p < paths.getLength(); p++) {
    path = paths.getAt(p);
    for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
      bounds.extend(path.getAt(i));
    }
  }

  return bounds;
  }
}

// Polygon containsLatLng - method to determine if a latLng is within a polygon
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.containsLatLng = function(latLng) {
// Exclude points outside of bounds as there is no way they are in the poly
var bounds = this.getBounds();

if(bounds != null && !bounds.contains(latLng)) {
  return false;
}

// Raycast point in polygon method
var inPoly = false;

var numPaths = this.getPaths().getLength();
for(var p = 0; p < numPaths; p++) {
  var path = this.getPaths().getAt(p);
  var numPoints = path.getLength();
  var j = numPoints-1;

  for(var i=0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    var vertex1 = path.getAt(i);
    var vertex2 = path.getAt(j);

    if (vertex1.lng() < latLng.lng() && vertex2.lng() >= latLng.lng() || vertex2.lng() < latLng.lng() && vertex1.lng() >= latLng.lng()) {
      if (vertex1.lat() + (latLng.lng() - vertex1.lng()) / (vertex2.lng() - vertex1.lng()) * (vertex2.lat() - vertex1.lat()) < latLng.lat()) {
        inPoly = !inPoly;
      }
    }

    j = i;
  }
}

return inPoly;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting rid of the form and instead set the onClick of the 'Go!' button to showAddress(). I tested this in IE7, Chrome, and Firefox and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I removed the onsubmit and action elements from the form and set the onclick as you said but it didnt work. I eventually removed the form altogether and put the input field in a "div" tag. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using jQuery to run your initialization code and for ajax.  Instead of using body.onload, use this:

```
$(function(){
  initialize();
}) ;
```

And for ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "xmloutput2.xml",
  success: function(data){
     // handle result
  }
});
```

If the problem is that your form is submitting to the server and causing a page reload, you need to return false from the showAddress() function, and use onsubmit="return showAddress();":

```
<form onsubmit="return showAddress();" action="#">
    <input id="search" size="60" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
    <input type="button" onclick="clearmarkers();" value="Clear markers" />
</form>

...

function showAddress () {
    ....
    return false ;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I loaded the Jquery library, removed the body.onload function and replaced the initialize function and the microajax script with your suggestions above but this did not solve the problem. Is Jquery a cross-browser script? Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Yes, jQuery is cross-browser.  Could you post your latest code, and maybe a sample xmloutput2.xml file, so I can try to reproduce your issue?  Also, try using the IE developer tools to see if you get any javascript errors in the console.

Comment: I think you need to return false from showAddress() if you don't want the form to be submitted to the server, and the page reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying  version

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.19"></script>
```

Your getting the experimental version if you do not specify a version.  I found the experimental version has problems with IE11